# How to tell mathematically which line i should start making the grid with

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm about to make a photos grid that its lines contain alternatively 2 and 3 photos using javascript. The question is: How to tell mathematically which line i should start making the grid with (a line with 2 photos or 3) in order to prevent that the last line contains 1 photo

```
| 2 photos | ..  |
| -------- |-----|
| 3 photos | ... |
| -------- |-----|
| 4 photos | ..  |
|          | ..  |
| -------- |-----|-----|
| 5 photos | ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  | 
| -------- |-----|-----|
| 6 photos | ... |
|          | ... |
| -------- |-----|
| 7 photos | ..  |
|          | ... |
|          | ..  |
| -------- |-----|
| 8 photos | ... |
|          | ..  |
|          | ... |
| -------- |-----|
| 9 photos | ..  |
|          | ... |
|          | ..  |
|          | ..  |
| -------- |-----|-----|
| 10 photos| ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
|          | ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
| -------- |-----|-----|
| 11 photos| ... |
|          | ..  |
|          | ... |
|          | ... |
| -------- |-----|-----|
| 12 photos| ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
|          | ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
|          | ..  | ..  |
| -------- |-----|-----|
| 13 photos| ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
|          | ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
|          | ... | ... |
| -------- |-----|-----|
| 14 photos| ..  |
|          | ... |
|          | ..  |
|          | ... |
|          | ..  |
|          | ..  |
| -------- |-----|-----|
| 15 photos| ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
|          | ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
|          | ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
| -------- |-----|-----|
```

edited

```
| -------- |-----|-----|
| 7 photos | ..  | ... |
|          | ... | ..  |
|          | ..  | ..  |
| -------- |-----|-----|
```

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt(s) at solving this problem.

Comment: I do not get the question. I think you should explain more about the "rules" for your goal. I do not see anythign which might result in the last line having 1 photo instead of 15. And I do not see any influence from the first line being 2 or 3 photos on that especially. Maybe you can show some examples which you did manually.

Comment: @Scott Hunter: my attempt is endless if...else clauses

Comment: Why can't 9 be 3 rows of 3, or (2,2,3,2)?  Why can't 6 be 3 rows of 2?

Comment: let's take 8 photos as an example: if i start with 2 photos:  2 3 2 1

Comment: I see a conflict between "contain alternatively 2 and 3 photos" and your example for 4: 2,2. Similar for 6, 11, ... Can you be more precise about the rule you want to obey?

Comment: @ Scott Hunter: 9 be 3 rows of 3, or (2,2,3,2) is not applicable on all numbers, telling which line to start with is applicable on all numbers

Comment: @Yunnosch: the goal is to make the grid lines with 2 or 3 photos. the last line is the rest of the photos (2 or 3 but not 1)

Comment: That is much easier than what you wrote in the question. Please be precise.

Comment: I want to get alternative lines and at the same time avoid getting the last line in one picture. For every number i can do it

Comment: @Adeltaf You say "For every number I can do it", but your example contradicts this many times. "4 = 2+2" does not have alternating lines of 2 and 3. Neither does "6 = 3+3", "11 = 3+2+3+3", and many others. Anything that leaves a remainder of 1 or 4 when divided by 5 cannot be represented as a sum of alternating 2's and 3's.

Comment: @Raymond Chen The last line doesn't count, it contains the rest, what matters is it contains more than one photo (4-> the rest is 2: i can't start with 3: 3 1) (6-> the rest is 3: i can't start with 2:  2 3 1) (11-> the rest is 3 i can't start with 2: 2 3 2 3 1)

Comment: You wrote "lines contain alternatively 2 and 3 photos." You never mentioned that the last line doesn't count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you alternate 2 and 3 photos, what matters is the total modulo 5. (operator `%`)

With `N =  Math.floor(total / 5)` (whole division)

If `total % 5 = 0` => you can start with either 2 or 3. You'll have 2N rows.

If `total % 5 = 1` => start with 3. You'll have 2N rows, and the last one will be 3 (not 2).

If `total % 5 = 2` => start with 2. You'll have 2N + 1 rows.

If `total % 5 = 3` => start with 3. You'll have 2N + 1 rows.

If `total % 5 = 4` => start with 2. You'll have 2N + 2 rows, and the last one will be 2 (not 3).

Only case this doesn't work is if you have only one photo.